# Is there a faster alternative to np.where for determining indeces?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like this:

`arrayElements = [[1, 4, 6],[2, 4, 6],[3, 5, 6],...,[2, 5, 6]]`

I need to know, for example, the indices where an arrayElements is equal to 1.

Right now, I am doing:

`rows, columns = np.where(arrayElements == 1)`

This works, but I am doing this in a loop that loops through all possible element values, in my case, it's 1-500,000+. This is taking 30-40 minutes to run depending how big my array is. Can anyone suggest a better way of going about this? (Additional information is that I don't care about the column that the value is in, just the row, not sure if that's useful.)

Edit: I need to know the value of every element separately. That is, I need the values of rows for each value that elements contains.

Comment: What is a typical size of `arrayElements`?

Comment: Usually its about [range(1E5,5E5), 9]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `np.isin` (see [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)), you can test for multiple element values.
For example:

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
check_for = np.array([1,2])

locs = np.isin(a, check_for)
# [True,  True, False, False]

np.where(locs)
#[0, 1]
```

Note: This assumes that you do not need to know the indices for every element value separately.

In the case that you need to track every element value separately, use a default dictionary and iterate through the matrix.

```
from collections import defaultdict

tracker = defaultdict(set)

for (row, column), value in np.ndenumerate(arrayElements):
    tracker[value].add(row)
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but am confused how this will be any faster. Once I have my True/False result, I'll still need to find which rows have True values which you've suggested using np.where for. It seems like one additional line to my code that offers no speed up because I will still need to use np.where?

I could be missing something though?  EDIT: The issue is that I need to konw the indices for every element separately. Thank you though.

Comment: In that case, you could think about the problem in this way: You have one matrix in memory that remains static, and 500k+ values you want to check. Most of those values will probably never occur. Rather than iterating over that many values, iterate over the one matrix. For each element you encounter at row `x`, you can now add row `x` to that values dictionary, such that dict[value] = [row1, row2, ...]. I.e., you keep a default dictionary with element values as keys, and a set of rows as value.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean by name of the element, but I don't think it will be a problem.

For example, you are interested in the value 1, that is, you are interested in np.where(arrayElements == 1). Then, if you iterate through arrayElements, and you are in the second row (so the row index is 1), nothing goes wrong if you encounter the value 1. The program will call 

`tracker[1].add(1)`

And at a later moment, you can query `tracker[1]`, and it will return 1. This output means that the value 1 was seen in the second row (the row with index value 1). Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I realized my follow up question made no sense. This has solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Perfect, glad to help!

Comment: If I may ask one follow up question, once I have my dictionary, and I query a position, as you suggested, tracker[1], it will return something like {1, 345, 2819, ..., 12389}. Is there a way to just have that as a list or array rather than a {} type? (I can change it to a string and replace the "{}" with "", but that doesn't seem like the designed method of doing this.

Comment: So the reason I suggested a dictionary with sets is that sets only have unique elements. You could use a list instead of a set if you don't care about duplicates, or if you're interested in how often arrayElements == 1 in a specific row. In that case you would have `tracker = defaultdict(list)`, and `tracker[value].append(row)`. Or you could simply cast the set that `tracker[1]` returns into a list with `list(tracker[1])`.

Answer (score 3):

So you are generating thousands of arrays like this:

```
In [271]: [(i,np.where(arr==i)[0]) for i in range(1,7)]                                                
Out[271]: 
[(1, array([0])),
 (2, array([1, 3])),
 (3, array([2])),
 (4, array([0, 1])),
 (5, array([2, 3])),
 (6, array([0, 1, 2, 3]))]
```

I could do  the == test for all values at once with a bit of broadcasting:

```
In [281]: arr==np.arange(1,7)[:,None,None]                                                             
Out[281]: 
array([[[ True, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False,  True, False],
        [False,  True, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False,  True, False],
        [False,  True, False]],

       [[False, False,  True],
        [False, False,  True],
        [False, False,  True],
        [False, False,  True]]])
```

and since you only care about rows, apply an `any`:

```
In [282]: (arr==np.arange(1,7)[:,None,None]).any(axis=2)                                               
Out[282]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

The `where` on this is the same values as in Out[271], but grouped differently:

```
In [283]: np.where((arr==np.arange(1,7)[:,None,None]).any(axis=2))                                     
Out[283]: 
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]),
 array([0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

It can be split up with:

```
In [284]: from collections import defaultdict                                                          
In [285]: dd = defaultdict(list)                                                                       
In [287]: for i,j in zip(*Out[283]): dd[i].append(j)                                                   
In [288]: dd                                                                                           
Out[288]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {0: [0], 1: [1, 3], 2: [2], 3: [0, 1], 4: [2, 3], 5: [0, 1, 2, 3]})
```

This 2nd approach may be faster for some arrays, though it may not scale well to your full problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looping over the values and indices using [`numpy.ndenumerate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html) and using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), or [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) where the keys are the values in the array.

Comment: Wasn't from me, I don't have enough rep to down vote anyway

Comment: Just so you know, your solution was the right one, so, thank you.

Comment: @tc_questions BTW, as the question asker, you are able to Upvote any answers you think are the helpful, and Accept the best one. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information.